# Ionic 3 form is not sending values to the back-end

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

We are trying to login on the app. The point is that with the same back-end Angular based web site is working perfectly. This issue is happening only with ionic. When you fill the login form inputs it throws empty fields are not allowed. This error message is coming from back-end. It means that it doesn't send values to the back-end. Here is the code:

```
export class LoginPage {
  loading: any;
  tabElement: any;
  SigninForm: FormGroup;
  forbiddenEmails: any;
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private authProviders: AuthProvider,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    private tokenProvider: TokenProvider,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.tabElement = document.querySelector('.tabbar.show-tabbar');
    this.SigninForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: [null, [Validators.required]],
      password: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    if (this.tabElement) {
      (this.tabElement as HTMLElement).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    if (this.tabElement) {
      (this.tabElement as HTMLElement).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }




  LoginUser() {
    this.ShowLoader();
    this.authProviders.LoginUser(this.SigninForm.value).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.tokenProvider.SetToken(data.token);
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.loading.dismiss();
          this.navCtrl.setRoot('TabsPage');
        }, 2000);
      },
      err => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        if (err.error.msg) {
          this.SHowErrorAlert(err.error.msg[0].message);
        }

        if (err.error.message) {
          this.SHowErrorAlert(err.error.message);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  RegisterPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push('RegisterPage');
  }

  SHowErrorAlert(message) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Login Error',
      subTitle: `${message}`,
      buttons: ['OK'],
      cssClass: 'alertCss'
    });

    alert.present();
  }

  ShowLoader() {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Athenticating...'
    });
    this.loading.present();
  }
}
```

`HTML`

```
<ion-content class="sign" padding>
  <div class="layer">
  <div class="appForm" ion-fixed padding margin-bottom style="position: absolute !important; top: 0%; bottom: 0%; left: 0; margin-bottom: 1%;">
      <form [formGroup]="SigninForm">
    <ion-list style="margin-top: 30% !important">
      <ion-item>
          <div class="logo">
              <h2>MyDreamLove</h2>
            </div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input class="input-field" formControlName="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div *ngIf="!SigninForm.get('username').valid && SigninForm.get('username').touched"
      class="help-block">Please enter a valid username!</div>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-input class="input-field" formControlname="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div *ngIf="!SigninForm.get('password').valid && SigninForm.get('password').touched"
      class="help-block">Please enter a valid password!</div>
      <button ion-button block class="login-button" (click)="LoginUser()">Login</button>

      <p class="signin">
        <button class="register-button" ion-button block clear (click)="RegisterPage()">Sign Up</button>
      </p>
    </ion-list>
</form>
  </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

My team mate posted full code here:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17398

Why its not sending input values to the back-end for checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, when you press the Login button, the password will always be null.

**Reason:**

In your HTML, For Password field you have given **formControlname** instead of **formControlName**. Notice the casing, **N** is capital in Name. Try correcting that and see whether it works.